# Create a commerce product and add it to cart using Services

Tags: commerce, services

I am using **[commerce_services](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_services)** module and **poster** as addon in firefox for my services. I want to create a commerce product and add it to cart using Services. I don't know what are the parameters and url to be provided. Please help...

Here is the poster.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question little more clearly?

Comment: The functions implemented in the `Commerce Services Implementations` section here contain functioning examples related to JavaScript: https://github.com/signalpoint/commerce/blob/7.x-1.x/commerce.js

Comment: I have updated my post with an image.. I think now its clear about poster add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the [Commerce service's README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_services/tree/README.txt) which includes a bit more detail on what kind of abilities it brings out of the box.

> The following grid indicates what callbacks have been defined so far
>   out of the current target set of resources:

```
Resource         | Index | Retrieve | Create | Update | Delete
-----------------|-------|----------|--------|--------|--------
product-displays |   Y   |    Y     |   -    |   -    |   - 
products         |   N   |    N     |   -    |   -    |   - 
carts            |   N   |    -     |   -    |   -    |   - 
orders           |   N   |    N     |   N    |   N    |   N
```

> The additional relationships and targeted actions are slated for
>   development:
>
> product-displays: products products: add to cart carts: empty, convert
>   orders: payments

So then the question is: Can you do what you want with commerce_services?

**Can you create a product?** *Not according to the README*

**Can you add a product to a cart?** *Not according to the README*